# All-Round, Versatile, Everyday - For Food

Tags: synonyms

I need to come up with a creative, catchy way to describe a food item (2-3 words), and I have been given the following words as a starting point

- versatile
- everyday
- all-round

Any ideas on what I can use to summarise these but in a "marketing" lingo? It is for packaging design.

I've come up with some options but they don't describe the key words. I am stuck. Here they are:

the traditional classic

the classic choice

traditional choice

real good

the original creamy/tangy

the traditional creamy/tangy

your daily choice

daily favourite

everyday favourite

classic favourite

Comment: It's my first time here. But with that kind of attitude, last time. Thanks for nothing

Comment: Be nice.

Whether you've come to ask questions, or to generously share what you know, remember that we’re all here to learn, together. Be welcoming and patient, especially with those who may not know everything you do. Oh, and bring your sense of humor. Just in case.

Comment: Will the phrase describe the packaging, or the food item, and what is the food item, to get a better idea of the phrase needed?

Comment: If you’re marketing to/in the US, I’d definitely try to work in “savory” because I think it’s brilliant how “Madison Avenue” uses that word to replace the “nasty” word “salty” while at the same time benefiting from the word’s “tasty/agreeable/pleasing sense: [Our products are] “Savory classics” [that epitomize] “Savory versatility.” If the 2-3 word limit isn’t absolute, you could even use an idiomatic phrase that’s a fairly well-known synonym for “versatile”:  [Our products are/will become] “the/that [savory] little black dress in/of your pantry.”

Answer (score 1):

A food that someone consumes on a daily basis is called a dietary ***staple***.

Comment: Correct. However that word isn't going to entice someone to purchase the product.

Comment: Try _quotidian_.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure you remembered to bring your own sense of humour, but regardless, how about

> **Flexible, Familiar, Classic**

By pairing familiar and classic, you can convey the idea that even if it is 'everyday' it isn't down-market.

Answer (score 0):

I can come up with **"your delicious choice"** or **"everyone's favorite"**.

Depending on the food item, **"the traditional classic"** may fit perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're into the world of marketing, then all bets are off in terms of "proper" language. You could turn to manufactured words like *Mmmday* or *Yumday* to represent the everyday nature of the foodstuff.

In terms of versatility, that's harder without knowing if it's an ingredient, an accompaniment or something else - fish fingers hardly scream flexibility, for example, although the humble potato is the very epitome of versatility. You may be better off using a phrase that captures the *from soups to desserts* sort of concept, if that's the versatility you're after.